# How to get environment variables in ECS container?

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-cli

What AWS CLI command should I be using to access the environment variables in an AWS ECS cluster's task's container?

I've seen `describe-cluster`, `list-tasks`, `describe-tasks`, `describe-container-instances`, etc... I can't seem to find one that lets me look at environment variables.

Is this doable via the AWS CLI?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Environment variables are defined inside the container and some are passed in the task definition. So you can use [describe-task-definition](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/describe-task-definition.html) to see the extra variables.

To get the default environment of the container image, you can [register-task-definition](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/register-task-definition.html) for task with command 'env' and the specific container image for which you want to find out and then [run-task](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/run-task.html) this task.